# multipart identifiers not found when using a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a query that I've written that runs fine, but any time I reference an object that is in a temp table that I created Microsoft sql server 2008 will underline that reference and tell me that it can't find the object. The weird thing is that the code works perfectly fine.
This is how I created my temp table

SELECT * Into #temp from MY_Table where Date >= '2013-09-17'

Then in my query I have
Select m.columnName
From #temp m

The query works, but sql server management studio says that it cant find the m.columnName.

Is there any way to fix this? Should I create the temp table differently?

Comment: Could you provide the complete code? It's not clear where the problem may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/788513/server-management-studio-intellisense-does-not-remember-temp-tables).

To make it recognize it, you can create the temp table first and then insert the data. Here is the example picture from the link above where you can see the way intellisense works and doesn't:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't know it was a known bug. To follow up, if you don't mind, How do I create a temp table from a subset of an already created table? I know I can use the syntax Create #temp but then I have to state the column names and types. I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: @user2693117. That is possible using the way that this bug is related to and you are doing already. You won't get intellisense for that but you can still use it.

Comment: @user2693117. And by the way. If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.